# Creating a PowerShell session to Microsoft Exchange

Tags: powershell, microsoft-exchange

I'm trying to connect to Microsoft Exchange through PowerShell but I keep getting a "access denied" error.
I'm using a global administrator with a business license to connect so that shouldn't be the problem.

The command I run:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

Error message:

> ```
> New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server
> outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access
> denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
> Help topic. At line:1 char:12 $Session = New-PSSession
> -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Conne ...
> + CategoryInfo: OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession],
> PSRemotingTransportException FullyQualifiedErrorId :
> AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed
> ```

Comment: Do you have MFA enforced on that account? In that case, you won't be able to use Basic Authentication and you must use new modules to connect

Comment: I don't have MFA enabled on that user, but I always get a recommendation on the sign in page that I should set it up, could that be the problem?

Comment: This is not a coding problem but a problem with your account OR the config of Exchange Online (basic auth). This question is out odlf scope for stackoverflow. The tip I can give you: use the ExchangeOnline Powershell module (the old way of connecting will be disabled soon anyway)

Comment: @MajdNakhleh yes, I suspect that could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, I'll try correcting the user rights and see if that helps.